# What are the differences between a leftist tree and a skew heap?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, priority-queue

Leftist trees and skew heap are similar data structures. I want to check the differences between them. They are described here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leftist_tree

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_heap

It says:

> However merging leftist heaps has worst-case O(log n) complexity while merging skew heaps has only amortized O(log n) complexity.

What is the other advantages and disadvantages, except the better performance of merging?

Thank you.

Comment: Amortized complexity is described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis

Answer (score 0):

The short version:

- Skew heaps use less memory than leftist heaps.
- A variation on skew heaps (bottom-up skew heaps) are asymptotically faster than leftist heaps, in an amortized sense.

The long version:

In the 1980s, when skew heaps were invented, there was a burst of research activity into the following question: is it possible to build data structures that do not maintain any explicit balance information / try to keep a reasonable shape, yet match the time bounds of “classical” data structures? This area of research led to structures like splay trees, Fibonacci heaps, pairing heaps, link/cut trees, and skew heaps that either kept pace with or outperformed existing data structures in an amortized rather than worst-case sense.

The top-down skew heap is one such data structure. It manages to hit the same time bounds as a leftist heap on all operations (in an amortized sense) without requiring nodes to store any explicit information about the tree shape. While a leftist heap requires each node to store the length of the shortest path from the node off the tree, swapping nodes to ensure each node’s right path is a faster way off the tree, skew heaps just need left and right child pointers and swap nodes regardless of the shapes or sizes of their left and right subtrees. This reduces the memory required by the data structure (though admittedly not by much) and is an interesting theoretical result in its own right.

There’s another variation on skew heaps, though, that do outperform classical leftist heaps. The bottom-up skew heap introduced in the original paper on the subject works by melding the two heaps bottom-up rather than top down, walking up the right spines of the heaps rather than walking down them. These heaps support meld in amortized O(1) rather than amortized O(log n), and thus (in an amortized sense) are strictly better than leftist heaps. However, they need three pointers per node rather than one.

As for which approach would be fastest in practice, that’s something that you’d need to benchmark on an actual machine to determine. I’d be curious to see how the three approaches compare!